# Is there a quicker method than nested forEach loops like shown in javascript?

Tags: javascript, foreach

There is a calendar view that renders every time the month is changed. When that month is changed there is a GET request made that gets all of the reservations for that particular month and year in view. Each day cell has a YYYYMMDD class. If the date in the response matches the day cell class a `<div>` is appended to that day cell `<div>`. The below method is working, but is there a quicker way to do this? As the below checks each response one by one and all the the day cells one by one which takes a little bit of time to compute.

**Updated per comment**

```
getReservations(url)
.then(response => {
    let monthDayCells = document.querySelector("#month-calendar").querySelectorAll(".day-cell");
    response.forEach(reservation => {
        monthDayCells.forEach(dayCell => {
            if (dayCell.classList.contains(reservation.date)) {
                const dayCellItem = document.createElement("DIV");
                dayCellItem.classList = "calendar-event";
                dayCellItem.innerHTML = `<span class="time">${reservation.startTime} - ${reservation.endTime}</span>`;
                dayCell.appendChild(dayCellItem);
            }
        });
    });
})
```

Comment: Move `let monthDayCells = ...` out of the `.forEach()` callback.

Comment: Try to improve the "performance" of a piece of code only after you have determined with a profiler that this piece of code is really a bottleneck.

Comment: `reservations.forEach(r => document.querySelector("." + r.date))`

Comment: It looks like you already know what the element you want to append the reservation to. Change your querySelector to `\`#month-calendar .${reservation.date}\``. Then append to that. If it's not found, skip to the next reservation.

Comment: Jason Miller, author of Preact, said a while back in a [jsconf talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LY6y3HbDVmg) something to the effect that `innerHTML` and such are very inefficient, compared with creating the `span` and text node. He also had a number of other tips that are probably pretty helpful for anyone wanting good performance in vanilla DOM manipulation.